# Azure SQL bacpac export fails after retirement of Azure Scheduler

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

After Azure Scheduler was retired in Jan 22 ([See more here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-scheduler-will-be-retired-on-31-january-2022/)), I am unable to export azure SQL database to bacpac.
I get the following error:

```
Export bacpac: One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.

Error SQL71501: Error validating element [jobs_internal].[visible_targets_formatted]: SqlView: [jobs_internal].[visible_targets_formatted] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [jobs_internal].[database_credentials].[C], [jobs_internal].[database_credentials].[name] or [jobs_internal].[targets].[C].
Error SQL71501: Error validating element [jobs]: SqlSchema: [jobs] has an unresolved reference to object [##MS_JobAccount##].
Error SQL71501: Error validating element [jobs_internal]: SqlSchema: [jobs_internal] has an unresolved reference to object [##MS_JobAccount##].
```

What exactly do I need to drop from the database to fix this.

Creation of the bacpac is part of Azure Web App backup (when option to back the database up is selected)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
You have to drop all objects in `[jobs]` and `jobs_internal` schemas.
I did mine in the following order:

1. stored procedures,
2. functions,
3. views,
4. foreign keys,
5. tables,
6. custom types,
7. schemas,
8. and finally users.

After this was done, I was able to export bacpac and also perform a web application backup that included the database.